# Path on network returning wrong results

Tags: qgis, shapefile, network

I have created a shapefile of polylines that represent a path with multiple intersections. Then I have used the networkx python library to create a network. At the first the results were satisfactory.

But when I tried to use the shortest path plugin of QGIS it returned a result like:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?